# How to change the notification badge color

Tags: android

Is it possible to change the color of the notification badge? Or is there any description how the color is selected by the system?

[image]

Comment: AFAIK its not possible .. Color is picked by System depending on the app icon color .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues and did some research... barely it is not possible. The System automatically chooses the Notification-Badge-Color depending on the Icon from your App.